# C conflicting types in headers and undeclared variables?

Tags: c, function, types, header

I'm getting the errors:

> conflicting types for 'complex'.(Line 4 of complex.h) Previous declaration of 'complex' was here. (Line 4 of complex.h)

And

> num1, num2, and ans undeclared. (First use in this function)

in the main program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "boolean.h"
#include "complex.h"
#include "complex_IO.h"
#include "complex_Arith.h"


int main (void){
    boolean quit=FALSE;
    boolean showmenu=TRUE;
    int menu_sel;
    while (!quit){
            if (showmenu){
                    printf("1 Add.\n");
                    printf("2 Subtract.\n");
                    printf("3 Multiply.\n");
                    printf("4 Conjugate.\n");
                    printf("5 Negate.\n");
                    printf("6 Toggle Menu.\n");
                    printf("7 Quit.\n");
                    printf("Enter Selection:");
                    scanf("%d",&menu_sel);
            }
            else{
                    printf("Enter Selection (4 to turn menu on):");
                    scanf("%d",&menu_sel);
            }
            switch (menu_sel){

                case 1: num1=Read_Complex();
                        num2=Read_Complex();
                        ans=Add_Complex(num1,num2);
                        Write_Complex(ans);
                        break;
                case 2: num1=Read_Complex();
                        num2=Read_Complex();
                        ans=Subtract_Complex(num1,num2);
                        Write_Complex(ans);
                        break;
                case 3: num1=Read_Complex();
                        num2=Read_Complex();
                        ans=Multiply_Complex(num1,num2);
                        Write_Complex(ans);
                        break;
                case 4: num1=Read_Complex();
                        num2=Read_Complex();
                        ans=Conjugate_Complex(num1);
                        Write_Complex(ans);
                        break;
                case 5: num1=Read_Complex();
                        num2=Read_Complex();
                        ans=Negate_Complex(num1);
                        Write_Complex(ans);
                        break;
                case 6: showmenu=!showmenu;
                        break;
                case 7: quit=TRUE;
                        break;
                default: printf("%d is not a valid option.\n", menu_sel);
            }
    }
}
```

I don't know if all the header files are needed but here's complex.h:

```
typedef struct {
    int real;
    int img;
} complex;
```

Comment: Does other headers include complex.h?

Comment: Yes. Complex_Arith.h and Complex_IO.h both do

Comment: So, you've got the issue...right? Check the preprocessed output, for clarity.

Comment: So complex.h shouldn't be in the other headers even when complex_arith.c and complex_io.c both use it?

Comment: You can include only `complex.h` in both of them, if viable.

Comment: It is viable for them to be in there. They both use the complex type

Comment: Are you using an #ifndef header guard?

Comment: No. Where would that be included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the second error:

> num1, num2, and ans undeclared. (First use in this function)

These variables are simply not declared anywhere.

You should probably declare them at the beginning of `main`:

```
int main (void){
    boolean quit=FALSE;
    boolean showmenu=TRUE;
    int menu_sel;

    complex num1, num2, ans;   // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

In `complex.h` (I'm assuming this is a custom header and NOT the official one) you need to add header guards. This prevents it from being processed twice by both `complex_IO.h` and `complex_Arith.h`. Read [here](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/c241man/node90.html) for more information.

```
/* complex.h */
#ifndef COMPLEX_H_INCLUDED__
#define COMPLEX_H_INCLUDED__

typedef struct {
    int real;
    int img;
} complex;

#endif
```

Also you should rename this (or point directly to it's location in the filesystem) since it [already exists](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/complex.h.html) as a standard header.

For your other error the variables aren't defined in the program causing the compilation error.

Comment: Oh I see. That worked. Do you have any idea about the undefined variables? If I try to define them in the main program, it breaks it even more

Comment: It might be safer to avoid reserved symbols for this: `_COMPLEX_H_INCLUDED_`.  Better use `COMPLEX_H_INCLUDED__` or simply `COMPLEX_H_INCLUDED`

Comment: Yeah, using complex.h as a custom library in general is a terrible idea. Updated, thanks.